# JQWidgets jqxGrid with jqxDropDownList as editor

Tags: javascript

Could someone provide the proper implementation method for utilizing the jqxDropDownList with checkboxes enabled as a grid column?

The following code is modified from the jqwidgets grid demo code ‘cellediting.htm’.

I've implemented an independent dropdownlist with checkboxes with no problems.

I've implemented a grid with dropdownlist (with out checkboxes) with no problems.

however, as soon as i put checkboxes: true in the initeditor i get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘instance’ of undefined jqxlistbox.js:7

In certain ‘more complicated’ scenarios, the checkboxes property will succeed with ‘createeditor’, but fail with initeditor.
This leads me to believe there is probably some asynchronous loading going on and im building the editor too quickly.

The following code fails because of the ‘checkboxes: true’ property. remove that and it works great.

```
<head>
    <title id='Description'>In order to enter in edit mode, select a grid cell and start typing, "Click" or press the "F2" key. You 
    can also navigate through the cells using the keyboard arrows or with the "Tab" and "Shift + Tab" key combinations. To cancel the cell editing, press the "Esc" key. To save
    the changes press the "Enter" key or select another Grid cell. Pressing the 'Space' key when a checkbox cell is selected will toggle the check state.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.edit.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcalendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxnumberinput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdatetimeinput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/globalization/globalize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/gettheme.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="generatedata.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // prepare the data
            var data = 
            [
                { firstname: 'joe', lastname: 'smith', sex: 'm' },
                { firstname: 'john', lastname: 'doe', sex: 'm' },
                { firstname: 'jane', lastname: 'doe', sex: 'f' }
            ];
            var source =
            {
                localdata: data,
                datatype: "array",
                updaterow: function (rowid, rowdata, commit) {
                    commit(true);
                },
                datafields:
                [
                    { name: 'firstname', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'lastname', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'sex', type: 'string' }
                ]
            };
            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
            // initialize jqxGrid
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: 685,
                source: dataAdapter,
                editable: true,
                selectionmode: 'multiplecellsadvanced',
                columns: [
                  { text: 'First Name', columntype: 'textbox', datafield: 'firstname', width: 80 },
                  { text: 'Last Name', columntype: 'textbox', datafield: 'lastname', width: 80 },
                  {  text: 'Sex', columntype: 'dropdownlist', datafield: 'sex', width: 195,
                    createeditor: function(row, cellvalue, editor)
                    {
                        var mydata =
                        [
                            { value: "m", label: "Male" },
                            { value: "f", label: "Female" }
                        ];
                        var mysource =
                        {
                            datatype: "array",
                            datafields:
                            [
                                { name: 'label', type: 'string' },
                                { name: 'value', type: 'string' }
                            ],
                            localdata: mydata
                        };
                        var myadapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(mysource, { autoBind: true });
                        editor.jqxDropDownList({ checkboxes: true, source: myadapter, displayMember: 'label', valueMember: 'value' });
                    }
                  }
                ]
            });
            // events
            $("#jqxgrid").on('cellbeginedit', function (event) {
                var args = event.args;
                $("#cellbegineditevent").text("Event Type: cellbeginedit, Column: " + args.datafield + ", Row: " + (1 + args.rowindex) + ", Value: " + args.value);
            });
            $("#jqxgrid").on('cellendedit', function (event) {
                var args = event.args;
                $("#cellendeditevent").text("Event Type: cellendedit, Column: " + args.datafield + ", Row: " + (1 + args.rowindex) + ", Value: " + args.value);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
    <div id='jqxWidget'>
        <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
        <div style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif; margin-top: 30px;">
            <div id="cellbegineditevent"></div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;" id="cellendeditevent"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone offer assistance?

Extra help!!
Additionally, it seems like once i select a value in the dropdown, the actual ‘value’ gets changed to the display ‘label’. i.e., (“Male” or “Female”), but in this example, the only valid data for the sex field would be ‘m’ or ‘f’.

I've asked the same question on the jqwidgets official forums (here: http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/dropdownlist-with-checkboxes-as-grid-column-editor/), and will post any answer they send here if they beat the community to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no DropDownList with Checkboxes Editor in the jQwidgets Grid. If there was such, I think that jQWidgets would at least have a sample about it so I suppose that you cannot use the DropDownList in such way in the jqxGrid widget.

Comment: jqWidgets team agrees.
"Unfortunately, It is not possible to use jqxDropDownList with CheckBoxes as cell editor in jqxGrid. There is no such built-in logic in the Grid’s DropDownList Editor as present."

I've requested the update their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a rather old post, but still...
I'm surprised to see the response from the JQWidgets team, since they themselves have such an example on their website, using a dropdownlist with checkboxes as a grid editor.
It is available at http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/cellcustomediting.htm
where the editor is used in the Products column.

Mihai

Comment: Interesting, they must have extended the functionality. I'll take the credit. #applause. thankyou! thankyou!

Comment: You should not be so surprised, because this post is from May 2013 and Custom Editors according to the Release Notes are added in August 2013.

Comment: @scripto, thank you for the clarification. That explains it, now I'm not surprised anymore :)